# Decimal TryParse in VBA

Tags: vba, decimal, tryparse

I am attempting to tryparse using decimal; however, I keep getting an "Object Required" run-time error. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong. I'm used to doing a tryparse in C#. This is VBA, so the language translation is not clicking just yet. Any help appreciated.

```
 Sub try()
        Dim val As Variant
        Dim res As Boolean

        res = Decimal.TryParse("2.5", val)
        MsgBox (res & ":" & val)
    End Sub
```

Comment: VBA doesn't have a TryParse. Vb.NET does....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [CInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and check for a specific error using On Error Goto.

Comment: In addition to this, IsNumeric works well, although not specific to decimals.

Answer (score 2):

`res = cBool(Val("2.5"))` should do the trick here, since any value <> 0 will evaluate as True