# Fat fingered decimal entry VBA for excel

Tags: vba, excel

I made a simple vba application that allows a user to enter data into excel. The data that's being entered had to be >= 1.99 ohms and can be 3.00 or higher.  Everything works great and it's been in use for over a year now. However, recently a user fat fingered a decimal point and didn't catch it until they entered the number.  VBA didn't like that and errored out. The format they entered looked like so: '.2.34'. I can't seem to figure out how to avoid this. Any suggestions?

I've tried using:

```
If Res.value <> Format(Number, "#.##") Then
    Msgbox ("blah blah")
    Res.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End if
```

This blocks those entries, but it also blocks correct entries.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655251/decimal-tryparse-in-vba

Comment: You can use `IsNumeric(Res.Value)` to check if it is a number and if it is a number you can check afterwards `If Res.Value => 1.99 And Res.Value  < 3.00` or something similar.

Comment: This worked, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add Data Validation rules on the typical ranges. Try this: **Data > Data Tools > Data Validation**